# Join grouped elements of list into one list with single-element in Python

Tags: python

I have a list which looks like this:

```
my_list = ['alex', 'test test test', 'dog cat']
# the list is not alaways the same ( it can have multiple groups )
```

I would like my list to become something like:

```
new_list = ['alex', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'dog', 'cat']
```

I tried:

```
combined = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(new_list))
```

but it's not outputing what I would like. I'm a little bit confused because as you can see I have groups of words that doesn't have a comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*map(str.split, my_list)))
['alex', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'dog', 'cat']
```

Comment: Nice solution. Accepted :)

Comment: More, if I have another list (`another_list = ['alex', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'dog', 'cat',....,'etc']`) how can I return `True` only if all the elements from the first list are also present in `another_list` ?

Comment: @Alex, for this post you got solution. now post another question. as this is my answer for your current post.